# Is LocalBroadcastReceiver + IntentService the correct practice?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I am trying to understand how this stuff works a little better.

So I learned about Runnables and Threads and ASyncTasks but apparently they have some serious drawbacks when it comes to configuration changes like rotating the screen.

Is it better to instead use IntentService for anything that should run in the background like SQL database commands, file-system procedures, Internet input/output processes, etc -- and then use LocalBroadcastReceiver to pass results back to the Activity?

Comment: Sure, an example would help

Answer (score 0):

> Is it better to instead use IntentService for anything that should run in the background like SQL database commands, file-system procedures, Internet input/output processes, etc -- and then use LocalBroadcastReceiver to pass results back to the Activity?

A service is needed if your UI might move to the background while the work is going on, and you are concerned that your process might be terminated while the work is going on. I tend to only worry about this if the work might exceed a second or so. Otherwise, a plain thread suffices.

Using an event bus, like `LocalBroadcastManager`, is a reasonable approach to let other components know when your service/thread is done with its work. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/LocalBroadcastManager) demonstrates this. Personally, I tend to use greenrobot's EventBus — [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/GreenRobot3) is a clone of the first one, but using EventBus instead of `LocalBroadcastManager`.

Comment: But what stops someone from rotating the phone in the middle of a thread process?

Comment: @user7025005: Nothing. But the thread does not care. You are using the event bus to let interested parties know about changes in state. Such a party would register on the event bus for updates (e.g., call `registerReceiver()` on `LocalBroadcastManager`), then do something to get the current state (e.g., check the singleton cache manager).

Answer (score 0):

Follow an example of a chat using one activity (chat activity) that run a class in service (realtime class). I use a mvc webapi to controll chat between chatters. When realtime receive a message "onConnected" or "ReceivedMessageServer" automatically send by LocalBroadcastManager to chat activity. This way in "onReceive" from BroadcastReceiver receives the message and runs other tasks.

a) ChatActivity.class

```
package br.com.yourapp;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Calendar;
import br.com.yourapp.model.MessageReceived;
import util.RealTime;

public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, 
View.OnKeyListener  , TextWatcher {
    AppController obj;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    private ListView lstChatLog;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
    private EditText txtChatMessage;
    private TextView lblTyping;
    private Button btnSendChat;
    private boolean resultRequest = true;
    private String errorMessage = "Internet is not working";
    private AlertDialog alertDialog;
    private AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder;
    String userType = "V";
    String spaces = "\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020";
    Calendar time;
    MessageReceived msg;
    private RealTime realTime;
    private final Context mContext = this;
    private boolean mBound = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        showProgressDialog();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        obj = (AppController) getApplicationContext();
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
        lblTyping = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblTyping);
        txtChatMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtChatMessage);
        txtChatMessage.setOnKeyListener(this);
        txtChatMessage.addTextChangedListener(this);
        btnSendChat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendChat);
        btnSendChat.setOnClickListener(this);
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        lstChatLog = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstChatLog);
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ChatActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                tv.setHeight(20);
                tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12);
                return view;
            }
        };
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(mContext, RealTime.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("Connect");
        filter.addAction("RecMsg");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ChatActivity.this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, filter);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().toString().equals("Connect")) {
                msg = (MessageReceived) intent.getExtras().getParcelable("msg");
                if (msg == null || msg.Message == null)
                    return;
                listAdapter.add(msg.Destiny + "" + msg.CurrentTime + " : " + msg.Message);
                lstChatLog.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                realTime.SendToSpecific(msg.Sender, "Hi !", userType, obj.getRiderId(), obj.getDriverId());
                hideProgressDialog();
            }
            else
            if (intent.getAction().toString().equals("RecMsg")) {
                msg = (MessageReceived) intent.getExtras().getParcelable("msg");
                if (msg == null || msg.Message == null)
                    return;
                if (msg.Message.equals("*0.+9=&!*#_&1|8%digi")) {
                    lblTyping.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else
                if (msg.Message.equals("*0.+9=&!*#_&1|8%"))
                {
                    lblTyping.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                else
                {
                    lblTyping.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    listAdapter.add(msg.Sender + "" + msg.CurrentTime + " : " + msg.Message);
                    lstChatLog.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(ChatActivity.this, R.raw.notify);
                    mp.setLooping(false);
                    mp.setVolume(100, 100);
                    mp.start();
                }
            }
         }
    };

    private final ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            RealTime.LocalBinder binder = (RealTime.LocalBinder) service;
            realTime = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
            realTime.Connect(obj.getRiderName(), userType, obj.getRiderId(), obj.getLatitudeRider(), obj.getLongitudeRider(), obj.getDriverId(), obj.getVehicieId());
            hideProgressDialog();
        }
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void SendToSpecific(String sender, String message, String userType, long userId, long operatorId) {
        realTime.SendToSpecific(sender, message, userType, userId,operatorId);
        if (!message.equals("*0.+9=&!*#_&1|8%digi") && !message.equals("*0.+9=&!*#_&1|8%"))
        {
            time = Calendar.getInstance();
            listAdapter.add(spaces + sender + " " + "(" + time.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + time.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ")" + " : " + message);
            lstChatLog.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            txtChatMessage.setText("");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            if (txtChatMessage.getText().length() > 0)
            {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.
                        INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (this.getCurrentFocus() != null)
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                SendToSpecific(obj.getRiderName(), txtChatMessage.getText().toString(), userType, obj.getRiderId(), obj.getDriverId());
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (txtChatMessage.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
            if (txtChatMessage.getText().length() == 1) {
                SendToSpecific(obj.getRiderName(), "*0.+9=&!*#_&1|8%digi", userType, obj.getRiderId(), obj.getDriverId());
            }
        } else {
            SendToSpecific(obj.getRiderName(), "*0.+9=&!*#_&1|8%", userType, obj.getRiderId(), obj.getDriverId());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnSendChat:
                if (txtChatMessage != null && txtChatMessage.getText().length() > 0) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.
                            INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    if (this.getCurrentFocus() != null)
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                    SendToSpecific(obj.getRiderName(), txtChatMessage.getText().toString(), userType, obj.getRiderId(), obj.getDriverId());
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void showProgressDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideProgressDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.hide();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        try {
            if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.
                INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (getCurrentFocus() != null)
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        mMessageReceiver.clearAbortBroadcast();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MenuPageActivity.class);
        obj.setLastActivity("Chat");
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }

    public void ShowAlert() {
        hideProgressDialog();
        if (resultRequest)
            errorMessage = "Internet is not working";
        alertBuilder.setTitle("Alert");
        alertBuilder.setMessage(errorMessage);
        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                arg0.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alertDialog = alertBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
        errorMessage = "";
        resultRequest = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

b) Realtime.class

```
package util;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import br.com.yourapp.model.MessageReceived;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.Platform;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.SignalRFuture;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.http.android.AndroidPlatformComponent;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.hubs.HubConnection;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.hubs.HubProxy;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.hubs.SubscriptionHandler1;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.ClientTransport;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.ServerSentEventsTransport;

public class RealTime extends Service {
    private HubConnection mHubConnection;
    private HubProxy mHubProxy;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    public RealTime() {    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        int result = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        startSignalR();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mHubConnection.stop();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        startSignalR();
        return mBinder;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public RealTime getService() {
            return RealTime.this;
        }
    }

    public void Connect(String userName, String userType, long userId, double latitude, double longitude, long driverId, long vehicleId) {
        mHubProxy.invoke("Connect", userName, userType, userId, latitude, longitude, driverId, vehicleId);
    }
    public void SendMessageToGroup(String userName, String userGroup, String userType, long userId, double latitude, double longitude, long vehicleId, short option)
    {
        mHubProxy.invoke("SendMessageToGroup", userName, userGroup, userType, userId, latitude, longitude, vehicleId, option);
    }

   public void SendToSpecific(String sender, String message, String userType, long userId, long operatorId)    
   {
        mHubProxy.invoke("SendToSpecific", sender, message, userType, userId, operatorId);
    }

    private void startSignalR() {
        Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());
        mHubConnection = new HubConnection("http://webapi.com");
        mHubProxy = mHubConnection.createHubProxy("ChatHub");
        ClientTransport clientTransport = new ServerSentEventsTransport(mHubConnection.getLogger());
        SignalRFuture<Void> signalRFuture = mHubConnection.start(clientTransport);
        try {
            signalRFuture.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            Log.e("SimpleSignalR", e.toString());
            return;
        }

        mHubProxy.on("onConnected",
                new SubscriptionHandler1<MessageReceived>() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(final MessageReceived msg) {
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Intent intent = new Intent("Connect");
                                intent.putExtra("msg", msg);
                                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(RealTime.this).sendBroadcast(intent);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                , MessageReceived.class);
    }

            }
        mHubProxy.on("ReceivedMessageServer",
                new SubscriptionHandler1<MessageReceived>() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(final MessageReceived msg) {
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Intent intent = new Intent("RecMsg");
                                intent.putExtra("msg", msg);
                                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(RealTime.this).sendBroadcast(intent);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                , MessageReceived.class);

}
```